# How do I put back an output token in a loop - Ruby Pagination?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, loops, pagination, token

I am using AWS config services to query some data. The results are paginated and a token is provided for the next page of responses. How do I reuse it to for so I can run it once?

example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/paging-responses.html

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'

QUERY = "
  SELECT
    resourceId
  WHERE
    resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::Instance'"

configservice = Aws::ConfigService::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1')

next_token = nil

loop do
  response = configservice.select_resource_config({
    limit: 100,
    expression: QUERY,
    next_token: next_token
  }.compact)

    response.results.each { puts response[:results].map { |i| JSON.parse(i, symbolize_names: true) } }

  break if response.next_token.nil?
  next_token = response.next_token
end
```

edit - thank Konstantin Strukov. This is what I've done now. it kind of works but seems to just repeat the same page multiple times rather than going to next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem properly because the task looks quite straightforward for me according to your own description:

1. Fetch the response, iterate over the data and process them somehow
2. If the response contains `next_token` repeat (1) using the next_token provided
3. Exit otherwise.

Assuming the last page response has nil as next_token (I didn't find an exact answer in the SDK docs so it's better to check this assumption first) something like the following could work:

```rb
require 'aws-sdk'

QUERY = <<~
  SELECT
    resourceId
  WHERE
    resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
QUERY

configservice = Aws::ConfigService::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1')

next_token = nil

loop do
  response = configservice.select_resource_config({
    limit: 100,
    expression: QUERY,
    next_token: next_token
  }.compact)

  response.results.each { ... } # do something with the results

  break if response.next_token.nil?
  next_token = response.next_token
end
```

P.S. I don't understand how

```
get_ec2.each do |response|
  puts response.map(&:next_token)
end
```

could work in your example taking into account that the response is [just a struct](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/gems/aws-sdk-configservice/lib/aws-sdk-configservice/types.rb#L4421), so its' `#each` simply iterates over structs' fields (and none of them responds to next_token). Does it really work?

Answer (score 0):

Konstantin Strukov - thank you for your help. I've worked out what I needed to do from your example.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'

QUERY = "
  SELECT
    resourceId,
    tags
  WHERE
    resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::Instance'"

configservice = Aws::ConfigService::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1')

next_token = nil

loop do
  response = configservice.select_resource_config({
    limit: 100,
    expression: QUERY,
    next_token: next_token
  }.compact)

    response.results.each {|i| puts JSON.parse(i, symbolize_names: true)}

  break if response.next_token.nil?
  next_token = response.next_token
end
```